# Why is Java's AbstractList's removeRange() method protected?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist, protected

Does anyone have any idea, *why* removeRange method in [AbstractList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) (and also in [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) is `protected`?  It looks like a quite well-defined and useful operation, but still, to use it, we're forced to subclass the List implementation.

Is there some hidden rationale? Seems quite inexplicable to me.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Yes, because that's not how you remove a range from outside code. Instead, do this:

```
list.subList(start, end).clear();
```

This actually calls `removeRange` behind the scenes.<sup>†</sup>

---

The OP asks why `removeRange` is not part of the `List` public API. The reason is described in Item 40 of Effective Java 2nd ed, and I quote it here:

> There are three techniques for shortening overly long parameter lists. One is to break the method up into multiple methods, each of which requires only a subset of the parameters. If done carelessly, this can lead to too many methods, but it can also help *reduce* the method count by increasing orthogonality. For example, consider the `java.util.List` interface. It does not provide methods to find the first or last index of an element in a sublist, both of which would require three parameters. Instead it provides the `subList` method, which takes two parameters and returns a *view* of a sublist. This method can be combined with the `indexOf` or `lastIndexOf` methods, each of which has a single parameter, to yield the desired functionality. Moreover, the `subList` method can be combined with *any* method that operates on a `List` instance to perform arbitrary computations on sublists. The resulting API has a very high power-to-weight ratio.

One can argue that `removeRange` doesn't have that many parameters and is therefore probably not a candidate for this treatment, but given that there's a way to invoke `removeRange` through the `subList`, there is no reason to clutter up the `List` interface with a redundant method.

---

<sup>†</sup> The [`AbstractList.removeRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#removeRange-int-int-) documentation says:

> This method is called by the `clear` operation on this list and its subLists. Overriding this method to take advantage of the internals of the list implementation can *substantially* improve the performance of the `clear` operation on this list and its subLists.

Also, see OpenJDK's implementation of [`AbstractList.clear`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l233) and [`SubList.removeRange`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l666).

Comment: Ok, it can done that way, but *why*? Seems awkward. Single elements can be removed from the list directly, why not multiple elements then?

Comment: @Joonas: Item 40 of Effective Java, 2nd ed describes the rationale for this. I'll paste in the relevant section in case you don't have the book.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Now it makes *some* sense :)

Comment: +1 (question answered). However, just because a rationale is given doesn't mean it makes sense. The process of shortening parameter lists hinders the ability of developers to understand operations available in an API, which works directly against the reason why the lists were shortened in the first place.

Comment: when using this method, how can i avoid "Cannot convert from List to ArrayList"

Comment: @clankill3r Do you have some example code? You should never need to convert to `ArrayList`.

Comment: So typical for java. Let's make it most complicated and least effective.

Comment: @vaxquis See [`AbstractList.clear`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l233) and [`SubList.removeRange`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l666). :-)

Comment: as a side note, did you notice that `removeRange` calls `arraycopy` unnecessarily when the `ArrayList` version is used on a range spanning till the very end of the list? http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l631 the `numMoved` is 0, so the entire arraycopy code could've been put into a single `if` (as done in `remove`); the difference is that a) arraycopy is a native call, incurring an overhead, b) arraycopy does *always* check params for correctness  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594046/java-native-method-source-code

Comment: @vaxquis I've edited the post to add those links. Re `ArrayList.removeRange`, yeah, since the `numMoved > 0` check is already in `ArrayList.remove`, it should also be in `removeRange` for consistency.