# Source code for the availableProcessors

Tags: java, runtime

Where can I find the soruce code/implementation for the `availableProcessors()` method in the  `java.lang.Runtime` class.

Comment: most likely it's a native function. Are you interested in the C implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594046/java-native-method-source-code
@Abhilash you'll find your answer there

Comment: The method getAvailableProcessors is not part of Runtime class.

Comment: @Abhilash you probably meant `availableProcessors()` instead

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a bit hard to find but the source code is here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/os.cpp

Look for `os::_processor_count`

The value is set in a OS-specific file. [Here is the Linux version](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp).

My strategy to find this was: Google for `site:http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ jdk7 runtime`

Then I opened the first link (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp) and removed the `synchronizer.cpp` from the URL. I can now see all the files in the `runtime/` folder. Then I went through the file names. `os.cpp` sounded interesting.

For the link above, I replaced the revision number with `tip` to make the link always point to the latest version.

Inside of that file, I saw `os::_processor_count`.

Googling for that gave me a couple of links again. `os_linux.cpp` looked promising.