# How does createNewFile() work internally?

Tags: java, file-io

createNewFile():

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname
> if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for
> the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not
> exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other
> filesystem activities that might affect the file.

How does it know if a file can be created or not? Does it depend on the host platform?

Comment: Evidently host platform API used (because of the atomicity).

Comment: In 2015 you don't want to use that anyway; use java.nio.file and `Files.createFile()`. At least it will throw a meaningful exception if it fails, unlike `File`'s `.createNewFile()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the `OpenJDK` repository. What you are looking for is [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.createNewFile%28%29). By looking into it, you can find, that this method calls `FileSystem.createFileExclusively(java.lang.String)`, where `FileSystem` is an abstract class and the concrete instance is obtained via `FileSystem.getFileSystem()` which is native method, specific for different platforms.

**EDIT** Example for Win32 File System is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/c228a234a3f3/src/windows/native/java/io/Win32FileSystem_md.c#l263)

Comment: Is the implementation of native methods as well in the OpenJDK repository ?

Comment: @Bionix1441 sure, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594046/java-native-method-source-code

Comment: @Bionix1441 I've made and edit and added a link to the source file