# How works ArrayList's removeRange method?

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList's removeRange works weirdly. Check the below sample code, I give to input reversely. I thought that the list has been removed reversely.

Ex: 3 to 1 means, the three elements are removed (3rd, 2nd, and 1st).

But, the output is totally confused me. Curious to know, how it works?

From the JavaDoc, I found the below statement. If toIndex < fromIndex, the system will throw IndexOutOfBoundException, But it doesn't. Is this bug?

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if fromIndex or toIndex is out of range
>   (fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex >= size() || toIndex > size() || **toIndex <
>   fromIndex**)

```java
import java.util.*;
public class TestRemoveRange extends ArrayList {

  public static void main(String arg[]){

    TestRemoveRange list = new TestRemoveRange();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("e");

    System.out.println("before remove : " + list);

    list.removeRange(3, 1);

    System.out.println("after remove (3, 1) : " + list); //[a, b, c, b, c, d, e]


  }     
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: From Index: 3 > To Index: 1  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeRange(ArrayList.java:664)  at TestRemoveRange.main(TestRemoveRange.java:15)`.

Comment: My java version is 1.8.0_121. I still face this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the actual source code might help to clarify your problem:

In **Java 8** the [`ArrayList.removeRange()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8f8015daf928/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l635) looks like this:

```
protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    modCount++;
    int numMoved = size - toIndex;
    System.arraycopy(elementData, toIndex, elementData, fromIndex,
                     numMoved);

    // clear to let GC do its work
    int newSize = size - (toIndex-fromIndex);
    for (int i = newSize; i < size; i++) {
        elementData[i] = null;
    }
    size = newSize;
}
```

In **Java 9** the [`ArrayList.removeRange()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l663) changed to this:

```
protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                outOfBoundsMsg(fromIndex, toIndex));
    }
    modCount++;
    shiftTailOverGap(elementData, fromIndex, toIndex);
}

private void shiftTailOverGap(Object[] es, int lo, int hi) {
    System.arraycopy(es, hi, es, lo, size - hi);
    for (int to = size, i = (size -= hi - lo); i < to; i++)
        es[i] = null;
}
```

As you can see in the snippets above both implementations use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to remove the items of the list. But only since Java 9 there is the check which throws the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `fromIndex > toIndex`.

Since `System.arraycopy()` [is implemented native the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594154/9662601) might be different on different platforms. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) it should behave this way:

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array. [...]
>
> If the `src` and `dest` arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos+length-1` were first copied to a temporary array with `length` components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions `destPos` through `destPos+length-1` of the destination array.

For `IndexOutOfBoundException` it says:

> If any of the following is true, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> - The `srcPos` argument is negative.
> - The `destPos` argument is negative.
> - The `length` argument is negative.
> - `srcPos+length` is greater than `src.length`, the length of the source array.
> - `destPos+length` is greater than `dest.length`, the length of the destination array.

So if you are running your example with **Java 8** or below you might get this result:

```
before remove : [a, b, c, d, e]
after remove (3, 1) : [a, b, c, b, c, d, e]
```

If you run your example with **Java 9** or above you will get this exception:

```
before remove : [a, b, c, d, e]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: From Index: 3 > To Index: 1
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeRange(ArrayList.java:769)
    at TestRemoveRange.main(TestRemoveRange.java:16)
```

Comment: Curious to know how the above code is works(version < 9)?

Comment: @sprabhakaran Yes, but that might be different on different platforms, because `System.arraycopy()` is implemented native. I added some more details for that to my post.