# Why is there no such removeRange() method in CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, copyonwritearraylist

Why in the `ArrayList` there is such a method and on the concurrent sibling there is not?

> protected void removeRange(int fromIndex,
>                  int toIndex)

Just curious about it it's not fundamental I can workaround it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a List which does this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey ArrayList implementation of List has that method. I was just curious why it's not present the same in the concurrent version.. maybe due some synchronization issues? I know how to workaround it. thanks

Comment: If any interested in the thing, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289183/why-is-javas-abstractlists-removerange-method-protected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this indirectly.

```
List<Integer> ints = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ints.add(i);
ints.subList(4, 7).clear();
System.out.println(ints);
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```