# Why removeRange method of ArrayList class is not working?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to use `removeRange` method for removing certain elements from `ArrayList`. I got to know about this method from here: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange%28int,%20int%29)

However when I tried it like this

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("AB");
al.add("BC");
al.add("CD");
al.add("DE");
al.removeRange(1, 3);
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method removeRange(int, int) from the type ArrayList<String> is not visible
```

Why am I not able to use this method? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since it a protected method , it is visible to only class ,package and subclasses.

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------
public      Y      Y        Y           Y
protected   Y      Y        Y           N
no modifier Y      Y        N           N
private     Y      N        N           N
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Hey Suresh, Thanks for answer but how can I delete the elements of certain specified range from ArrayList?

Comment: No you cannot. At a time  you can remove one element, remove in a loop or look at sublist() method. That might be useful.

Comment: Glad ,it helped. Look at the source code of removeRange method and see what they are doing. That will throw some idea.

Comment: Or you could extend ArrayList and expose it. But there might be good reasons it is protected.

Answer (score 27):

The short answer is: Use

```
al.subList(1, 3).clear();
```

---

The `removeRange(int, int)` method is `protected`. You can only invoke it from a subclass of `ArrayList` or from a class within the same package as `ArrayList`. See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

The only way to access the `removeRange` method is to subclass `ArrayList` and make the method public. E.g.

```
public class RangeRemoveSupport<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

  public void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    super.removeRange(fromIndex, toIndex);
  }

}
```

But then your code must use the subclass. Thus your code depends on this subclass and not just depends on `List` or `ArrayList`.

A utility class within the same package to access it is not possible. E.g.

```
package java.util; // <- SecurityException

public class RemoveRangeSupport {

    public static void removeRange(ArrayList<?> list, int from, int to){
       list.removeRange(from, to);
    }
}
```

This will cause a `SecurityException`

> **`java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util`**.

because you are not allowed to define classes in `java.util` for security reasons.

Nevertheless for other packages it might be a way.

I often use this strategy for tests. Then I put such a utility class in the same package as the production code to access some internals from tests that should normally not be accessible. This is an easy way without using a framework.

**EDIT**

> Is there perhaps a function to replace items from range X..Y, to new items of a possible different size?
>
> for example: this list "0,1,2,3,4", I replace from 1..3 with "a,b,c,d,e", will result with : "0,a,b,c,d,e,4".

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"));
List<String> subList = list.subList(1, 4);
subList.clear();
subList.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
System.out.println(list);
```

will output

```
[0, a, b, c, d, e, 4]
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a function to replace items from range X..Y, to new items of a possible different size? for example: this list "0,1,2,3,4", I replace from 1..3 with "a,b,c,d,e", will result with : "0,a,b,c,d,e,4".

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes I updated my answer

Comment: Nice. Doesn't it cause shifting of cells twice, though? I've created a new question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47416833/878126

Answer (score 3):

You can use: a1.subList(1, 3).clear();
It has already been discussed here:[Why is Java's AbstractList's removeRange() method protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289183/why-is-javas-abstractlists-removerange-method-protected)
It might help you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

`removeRange(int firstIndex, int lastIndex)` method is `protected` method in `ArrayList<Object>`. Protected method is accessed in class, subclasses and in package, but not public.