# ArrayList.removeRange option for Kotlin is missing in 1.3?

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Is there any function in Kotlin to remove a specific range of elements as in Java.

In Java we have a method called `removeRange` which can be extended and can be made useful.

```
expect class ArrayList<E> :MutableList<E>,RandomAccess{
    constructor()
    constructor(initialCapacity:Int)
    constructor(elements:Collection<E>)

    fun trimToSize()
    fun ensureCapacity(minCapacity:Int)

   // From List

    override val size:Int
    override fun isEmpty():Boolean
    override fun contains(element:@UnsafeVariance E):Boolean
    override fun containsAll(elements:Collection<@UnsafeVariance E>):Boolean
    override operator fun get(index:Int):E
    override fun indexOf(element:@UnsafeVariance E):Int
    override fun lastIndexOf(element:@UnsafeVariance E):Int

   // From MutableCollection

    override fun iterator():MutableIterator<E>

   // From MutableList

    override fun add(element:E):Boolean
    override fun remove(element:E):Boolean
    override fun addAll(elements:Collection<E>):Boolean
    override fun addAll(index:Int,elements:Collection<E>):Boolean
    override fun removeAll(elements:Collection<E>):Boolean
    override fun retainAll(elements:Collection<E>):Boolean
    override fun clear()
    override operator fun set(index:Int,element:E):E
    override fun add(index:Int,element:E)
    override fun removeAt(index:Int):E
    override fun listIterator():MutableListIterator<E>
    override fun listIterator(index:Int):MutableListIterator<E>
    override fun subList(fromIndex:Int,toIndex:Int):MutableList<E>
    }
```

> removeRange was added in 1.1 of Kotlin but was removed in 1.3

Comment: Have u checked this [removeRange](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/remove-range.html#removerange)

Comment: I couldn't find such a function while using  arraylist @NileshRathod

Comment: can you show me an example of it's usage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20748848/7666442

Comment: You can create extension function for this

Comment: I know i can create extension functions for that, I want to know there's any functions for it @NileshRathod

Answer (score 14):

`removeRange` is protected in kotlin, but this should do the trick:

```
array.subList(2, 4).clear();
```

Comment: cool, save my day man!

Comment: It's working, but in my case, I need to delete the first n number(like first 3) of index values.           val list = mutableListOf<Int>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5.6.7.8,9,10)
 list.subList(1..3).clear() 
 print(list)

Answer (score 3):

There is no clean way to do that. [Shermano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783238/shermano) is right. It's no nice, but it is the best way. Your options

**a)** Use `dropLast` or `drop`

However, you cannot use type casting for ArrayList

```
lis = lis.dropLast(1) as ArrayList<Int>
```

It gives a runtime error. One has to declare the variable like `MutableList`, that is almost the same.

```
   var lis = mutableListOf(2,3,4)
   lis = lis.dropLast(2) as MutableList<Int>
   println("dropLast: ${lis.size} ${lis[0]}")
```

It prints

```
dropLast: 1 2
```

You also can use `lis.dropLast(2).toMutableList()`

**b)** Use `for` statement

```
var lis=arrayListOf(2,3,4)   
for (i in lis.indices.reversed()) {
   if (i>=1 && i<=2) lis.removeAt(i)
}
println("for: ${lis.size} ${lis[0]}")
```

Notice that one needs to delete backwards.

It prints

```
for: 1 2
```

**c)** Use `subList`

```
   var lis = arrayListOf(2,3,4)
   lis.subList(1,3).clear()
   println("subList: ${lis.size} ${lis[0]}")
```

It prints

```
subList: 1 2
```

/*/

I prefer the third option encapsulated in some inline function.

```
inline fun <T> ArrayList<T>.delLen(ini:Int, len:Int=-1) {
  if (len == -1)
    this.subList(ini,this.size).clear()
  else
    this.subList(ini,ini+len).clear()
}
```

So

```
lis.delLen(0,2) // delete the 0th postion for 2 positions.
lis.dellen(1)  // delete from 1st postion forward.
```

I also like

```
inline fun <T> ArrayList<T>.delLast(n:Int=1) {
  this.subList(this.size-n,this.size).clear()
}
```

Examples

```
lis.delLast() // delete the last position
list.delLast(3) // delete last 3 positions
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this. Since there seems to be no method for this, you can create one using extension functions:

```kotlin
val IntRange.end: Int get() =
    last + 1

fun <T> MutableList<T>.subList(range: IntRange) =
    subList(range.first, range.end)

fun <T> MutableList<T>.removeRange(range: IntRange) =
    subList(range).clear()
```

Example usage:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf<Int>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
list.removeRange(2 until 4)
print(list)  // Outputs [0, 1, 4]
```