# Get Item between ranges of list kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I have list of int type for example. I want to pass **startingIndex** and **endingIndex** to get between items of that range in list. So How can I do this in efficient way in Kotlin.

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

**For example**

**Scenario 1**

**startingIndex** = `2`, **endingIndex** = `6`

List will returns items

**Expected Output**

```
3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

**Scenario 2**

**startingIndex** = `0`, **endingIndex** = `2`

List will returns items

```
1, 2, 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Kotlin's [**slice**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-parts.html#slice) function to get a part of the list by passing the range of indices.

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)

println(list.slice(2..6)) //prints [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

println(list.slice(0..2)) //prints [1, 2, 3]
```

For any collection related operations, the best way to find out would be to check Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#map) for collections, as a lot of operations are supported by Kotlin's standard library by default.

Comment: thanks for reply. `slice` will not modify the original list?

Comment: No, it would not modify the list.

Comment: @vivekmodi No, it won't…

Comment: is there any slice similar but can modify the original list?

Comment: seems removeRange is abstract and need to self-implemented, but found a trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903283/3260008

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use `List.subList(a, b)` method. It takes two parameters, starting and ending index.

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
println(list.subList(0,4)) //prints [1, 2, 3,4]
```