# How to use generics for type safety while using `removeRange` method of ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, methods

Since the method - `removeRange(int startIndex, int )` is protected, we need to use it in a class extending ArrayList. Below is my code -

```
public class MyClass extends ArrayList<String> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass arrayList1 = new MyClass();
        arrayList1.add("Zebra");
        arrayList1.add("Giraffe");
        arrayList1.add("Bison");
        arrayList1.add("Hippo");
        arrayList1.add("Elephant");

        MyClass arrayList2 = (MyClass) arrayList1.clone();
        MyClass arrayList3 = (MyClass) arrayList1.clone();

        System.out.println(arrayList1);
        System.out.println(arrayList2);
        System.out.println(arrayList3);

        arrayList1.removeRange(0, 3);
        arrayList2.removeRange(3, 5);
        arrayList3.removeRange(2, 4);

        System.out.println(arrayList1);
        System.out.println(arrayList2);
        System.out.println(arrayList3);
    }
}
```

Output -

```
[Zebra, Giraffe, Bison, Hippo, Elephant]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Bison, Hippo, Elephant]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Bison, Hippo, Elephant]
[Hippo, Elephant]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Bison]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Elephant]
```

Now to use type safety I need to write - `MyClass<String> extends ArrayList<String>` but doing so gives error in main method of `String[]` -

`MyClass.This cannot be referenced from a static context`

So how is it possible to use `generics` in `removeRange` method of ArrayList?

Comment: @Eritrean What is T?

Comment: “…we need to use it in a class extending ArrayList.”  No, you don’t.  `list.subList(startIndex, endIndex).clear()` will do the same thing.  No subclass needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to make `MyClass` able to store objects of any type, not just `String` is to introduce a *type parameter* `T` which fills in for the type.  The declaration will then be

```
public class MyClass<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

But then, you have to specify what `T` is when you declare a `MyClass` variable.  This means you'll need to change your variable declarations and initialisations to things like

```
MyClass<String> arrayList1 = new MyClass<>();
```

which tells the compiler what type to use in place of `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise:

> Since the method - removeRange(int startIndex, int ) is protected, we need to use it in a class extending ArrayList.

… is incorrect.

`removeRange` is not meant to be called from outside the class. So no need to create your subclass.

Instead, call [`List#subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) and [`List#clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#clear()).

```
list.subList( start , end ).clear() ;
```

See the Javadoc for [`AbstractList#removeRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#removeRange(int,int)):

> This method is called by the `clear` operation on this list and its subLists.

See Item 40 of [*Effective Java*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34927404) 2nd ed.

See discussion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2289183/).

Example code:

```
List< String > original = List.of( "Zebra" , "Giraffe", "Bison", "Hippo", "Elephant" ) ;

ArrayList< String > a1 = new ArrayList <> ( original ) ;
ArrayList< String > a2 = new ArrayList <> ( original ) ;
ArrayList< String > a3 = new ArrayList <> ( original ) ;

a1.subList( 0, 3 ).clear() ;
a2.subList( 3, 5 ).clear() ;
a3.subList( 2, 4 ).clear() ;

System.out.println( a1 );
System.out.println( a2 );
System.out.println( a3 );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/iHGUMX).

```
[Hippo, Elephant]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Bison]
[Zebra, Giraffe, Elephant]
```